# Problems with sfValidatorChoice

Tags: forms, symfony-1.4

I have some problems with sfValidatorChoice. This is the array for the choice:

```
$branches = array(123 => 'Value 1', 456 => 'Value 2', 789 => 'Value 3')
```

where the numbers are given IDs. To have a default value I do this:

```
$choices_branches = array_merge(array('default' => 'Bitte wählen'), $branches);
```

In the form class I do this:

```
$this->setWidgets(array(
    'branches'    => new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
                        'choices'  => $choices_branches,
                        'expanded' => false,
                        )),
...))
```

and this is the validator:

```
$this->setValidators(array(
  'branches'    => new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array_keys($branches))),
  ...
))
```

But when I choose for example Value 1 and try to submit the form I get an Invalid Error.

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

> Don't forget that numeric keys will be renumbered!

You should do the following:

```
$choices =  array(123 => 'Value 1', 456 => 'Value 2', 789 => 'Value 3');
$this->setWidget('branches', new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
    'choices'  => array('' => 'Bitte wählen') + $choices,
    'expanded' => false,
));
$this->setValidator('branches', new sfValidatorChoice(array(
    'choices' => array_keys($choices),
));
```